# How do you set the background color of a UINavigationbar programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I am using a cocoa iOS component from cocoacontrols.com, which is NOT using storyboards.  This class creates a new modal view and the modal view has a NavigationBar at the top. I am trying to get the color of the navigationBar to change.  In all my other views, which are storyboard based, I use a base class of STBaseViewController which sets the navigationBar as white.

I have changed this cocoacontrol class to be a STBaseViewController instead of a UIViewController, but it still is not changing my background to white.

```
@interface BZPasscodeFieldController : STBaseViewController
```

In the BZPasscodeFieldController, which they don't make any reference to a navigationbar, so I am not sure how its even showing up (again it has no storyboard's only xibs and they don't have navigationbars)?

Anyway, does anyone know how to make the navigationbar background color white programatically?

Further, in all my storyboard viewControllers that have a UINavigationBar, I have added a UIButton over the area where the title goes, so that I can easily change the font/style and also make it clickable. I need to add this same UIButton to the uinavigationBar of this BZPasscodeFieldController created programatically. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question about the button on the place of title of navigationBar. Each navigationBar has a `titleView` property, you can assign any view to it. For example take a look at this method, you can call it in your BZPasscodeFieldController:

```
- (void) setNavigationBarTitleButton
{
    UIButton* centralButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 44)];
    [centralButton setImage:navigationCentralButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [centralButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:TRUE];
    [centralButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goHigher) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = centralButton;

}
```

For your previous question the answers provided already are all correct, calling them in the right place(for example in AppDelegate's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: should make it work well, unless something is messed up in your custom view controller classes.

Comment: And you can just transfer your xib's into your storyboard, right? then just infer the navigation bar?

Answer (score 3):

**To Set Navigationbar Background Color:**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
```

**To set Navigationbar Tint Color:**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  It is still gray. Actually if I "po self.navigationController" it says the navigationbar is nil?  Then how would it show a navigationBar at all if its nil?

Comment: @jgervin where did you put it

Comment: viewDidLoad.  I am thinking its actually a navbar in a UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```